# communcation between node.js and processing

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, processing, osc

i'am working on a project where i receive data from mobile phones via websockets to a node.js server using socket.io. and this i want to pass to processing. The processing sketch is not running in the browser, it manage sounds, arduino, ... so i wonder what would be a good protocool to send the data to the processing sketch?

I did not found a way to use socket.io in processing, so i thought about using osc?
Or is there a other socket protocoll i can use between mobile phones, node, processing?

thanks!

Comment: Are you talking about Processing, the IDE, used with Arduino's?  Is the Arduino on the users side or server side?  Need more info on your setup.

Comment: Hey Chris, at the moment I'am not sure how to manage, the thing is i receive websockets to a node server and i want to pass them further, at the end i will play some sounds, videos and also a small windmachine witch is connected to a arduino board.

Comment: so thats why i thougt, i will bring them all together in processing and from there i will handle the inputs and trigger the hardware, thanks

Answer (score 0):

See if this shield will do the trick for you:  http://arduino.cc/en/Main/ArduinoEthernetShield  Found a few simple projects from google that seem to fit your description of what you want (turn something on/off from the web).

Node can be your server, with sockets.io, and node can most likely communicate over the web with this shield.  Note: I've never used it, just googled, saw a project that looks like what you are interested in.

EDIT:  Here is another possible solution:  http://xseignard.github.io/2013/06/25/interfacing-leap-motion-with-arduino-thanks-to-nodejs/ using: https://github.com/rwaldron/johnny-five